# Unable to access localStorage in ionic for ios 10

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ios10

I am trying to save APN id in localstorage for for my ionic app.It is failing for iOS10. I am using

```
($window.localStorage.registerPushId = data.registrationId);
```

to set a registration id in the local storage, but receiving an error saying

"cannot fetch registerPushId of undefined."

No localstorage saving operation seems to work for iOS10. However the same code runs for iOS9. Any idea, how I can access the local Storage for iOS10 in my project? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: yes,got the same error as you. any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a meta tag which is needed in case of iOS10.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * 'self' gap: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; ">
```

Also use $window.localStoarge instead of window.localStorage and remember to pass $window in the parameter.

Hope this solves the problem.